# Accessing 3rd party React component in web forms application

Tags: reactjs, webforms, material-ui

How can I incoporate a Material UI component (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/usage/) in web forms application. Following is what I have but this does not show the Button component

I have a ASPX file and I am using UMD to add references to React, Material UI and babel as follows:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material- 
ui.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

var prop1 = 'contained';
var prop2 = 'primary';

ReactDOM.render (
     <Button variant = {prop1} color = {prop2}> Hello World </Button>,
            document.getElementById('test')
     ); 

</script>
```

But when I try a sample without a referenced UI component as follows this works:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material- 
ui.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

class Greeting extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (<p>Hello world</p>);
        }
    }
ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting />, 
     document.getElementById('test')
    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that occurs is that `Button` is not defined.

You need to add `const {Button} = window['material-ui'];`.

You can find a UMD Material-UI example here:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/cdn/index.html

Below is a working snippet with a fixed version of your code.

```html
<div id="test">

</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

var prop1 = 'contained';
var prop2 = 'primary';
const {Button} = window['material-ui'];
ReactDOM.render (
     <Button variant = {prop1} color = {prop2}> Hello World </Button>,
            document.getElementById('test')
     ); 

</script>
```